# May I monitor and save data such phone call drops, phone call quality

Tags: ios, callkit, core-telephony

I'm testing an app for monitoring phone calls quality, but seems that even using CallKit or CallTelephony I cannot save data such length of the call , audio quality, or if the call drops.

In the end, seems I cannot measure this things, am I right?

yet checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980655/monitor-phone-call-length) and relative documentations, could someone give me confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've seen, you're definitely not going to be able to get that information at this point. It's just not part of the plugins and likely not something the OS allows third-party applications to access.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the call Duration by using `CallKit`, but you can't monitor audio quality. Also you will never get the phone number of the given call. You will only get the unique id for given call, and callbacks which gives the detail of given call that call get connected, disconnected, kept on hold etc. So based on connected and disconnected status - you can measure the call duration.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that I can monitor when a call is closed via CallKit? even if it is a non VOIP one? I cannot get info about monitoring a phone call via call kit, could you help me?

Comment: yes, even if you are having non-VOIP app, you can monitor calls start, end, etc. you can check for this 'CXCallObserverDelegate'  and 'CXCallObserver' for the same. The method in this delegate is going to be called when state of any call get changed. First try to do by yourself. If you are unable to do then let me know, i will surely help you.

Comment: thank for your help, I checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021317/get-phone-call-states-in-ios-10 and it is working, but only if app is in use, If I put it in background cannot print the status of the call. I tried to play around in app delegate, but no success

Comment: when app goes in background console gives me "Could not load IOSurface for time string. Rendering locally instead"

Comment: @biggreentree : I have not checked it in background, will check it and let you know